# running a PHP external file within a script via an if statement

Tags: php

I want to run an external script, within the current script (for tidyness purposes) based on a series of if and else if statements.

Essentialyl what I want do is this...

```
if ($business_type == "Restaurant"); {require 'scripts/php/insert.php'}

else if ($business_type == "Hotel"); {require 'scripts/php/insert-hotel.php'}
```

Is this i the right way to call this external script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the proper way of calling the scripts, but your syntax is just a little off :)

```
if ($business_type == "Restaurant"){
    require 'scripts/php/insert.php';
}
else if ($business_type == "Hotel"){
    require 'scripts/php/insert-hotel.php';
}
```

You might want to look into the documentation for Require and Include, but require is perfectly fine for what you're doing here.

Comment: Thanks for that. It doesn't run the script though. I want it to run the script as the if statement but without having to have the whole code in the same script. Really just to keep it tidy....does that make sense?

Comment: Would a better way to be to store the require as a variable? (what is the correct way to do that?)

and echo it out within the if and else if statements?

Comment: Is the the path to your two scripts correct? If they're in the same folder as the one that is running them, you would use only the file name:
`require 'insert-hotel.php';`

Comment: no the paths are correct, i have other requires in the script for Db_connections that have the same file path etc. SO should that just run within the script then based on the revised code you gave me?

Comment: It's strange because when i just add the ext script straight into the if statement it works absolutely fine.

Comment: If the paths are correct, the code in my answer should work. I just created some dummy files to test it for myself. If the code you're trying to execute is in a function in the other file, you may need to call that function after you require it, if it is not explicitly called there. `require 'insert-hotel.php'; myFunc();`

Comment: its a MySQL query called $insertSQL... do you think thats what it is?

Comment: As long as you connect to the database in either of the files before you execute the query, it should work fine. I've just tested this to confirm it. Are you getting any errors or is the code just not being executed?

Comment: This is my first account, unfortunately. I don't have the rep for chat yet.

Comment: if i just copy and past te code from the ext file into the if statement, that works. But then when i try and add the else if code, it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75207/discussion-between-beefstew-and-springheeled-jack).

Comment: its really strange. I know your answer is correct. I have marked it as so but i just dnt understand why my code is failing.